# Text and ListView in scroll behavior flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am experimenting with flutter and I came across with an issue. I have a text with my results derived from a service and a ListView (builder) displaying those results (as a card in order to have a nice box like layout).

My goal is, as the user scrolls the list, the result portion of the page (text) to be disappeared.

I tried SingleChildScrollView as described in https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html but it did not work.

Screenshot: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFHnw.png)

Any insights will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Update(widget tree)

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  body: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0),
        child: new RichText(
          text: new TextSpan(
            children: <TextSpan>[
              new TextSpan(
                text: this.model == null
                    ? "0"
                    : this.model.length.toString(),
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
              ),
              new TextSpan(
                text: ' Results',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new RefreshIndicator(
          key: refreshKey,
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: this.model?.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Model model= this.model[index];
              return new Card(child: new Text(model.id.toString()),);
            },
          ),
          onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Please provide code of your widget class also, to know how your current widget tree is structured.

Comment: You can try adding the results text in the ListView itself.
For example, you can only have a ListView and for the "0th" index, you can return a Text widget. And for other indexes, you can return your Card.

Comment: @Dhaval the zero index did the trick indeed. That's great thanks. However, I wonder if there is a more sophisticated way to to this. What if for example I had a **ListView(of cards)**, a **Text widget** and another type of widget, all of them at the same page having a scroll interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below given structure, which looks less hacky :p

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> results = List.generate(40, (int i) => "Result $i");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test Screen")),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Container(
           width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
            Text("RESULTS", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: results.map((String s) => Container(
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Card(child:Text(s)))).toList(),
            ),
          ]),
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ll give it a go and I will let you know.